# Add UIPickerView selection to TextField only when clicking done button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I created a UIPickerView with a done button in a toolbar. I would like to accomplish the following:

User selects a category in the UIPickerView and then taps the "done" button. Result should be that the UIPickerView and the Toolbar disappears and the Category TextField gets updated with the user's selection. I almost have everything right. The PickerView and the Toolbar disappear when the done button gets tapped. But the Textfield gets updated even before I tap the button. But I want the textfield only updated when the done button gets tapped.

Can anyone point me in the right direction where I have my error? Thanks

that is the code I used:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //disable saveButton
    [_saveButton setEnabled:NO];

    [self.picker removeFromSuperview];
    [self.pickerToolbar removeFromSuperview];

    //Initialize Data
    _pickerData = @[@"Item 1", @"Item 2", @"Item 3", @"Item 4"];

    //Connect Data
    self.picker.dataSource = self;
    self.picker.delegate = self;

    _textFieldCategory.inputView = _picker;
    _textFieldCategory.inputAccessoryView = _pickerToolbar;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// The number of columns of data
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

// The number of rows of data
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData.count;
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData[row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    self.textFieldCategory.text = _pickerData[row];
}

- (IBAction)doneButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self.picker removeFromSuperview];
    [self.pickerToolbar removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an instance variable, for example

```
NSInteger selectedRow;
```

In the `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` method, replace the line you have with

```
selectedRow = row;
```

And in the `doneButtonTapped:` method, add the line

```
self.textFieldCategory.text = _pickerData[selectedRow];
```

Comment: Done! sorry, system told me I had to wait 3 minutes before I could check it!